Mypy is not ignoring multiple errors
With the following configuration file mypy won't ignore override errors but import-type ones only
[mypy]
disable_error_code = import-untype,override

What's the correct way to specify multiple values for the disable_error_code setting?

You probably mean import-untyped (note the last d)? Please edit the question to provide more information, preferably as a [mre].

The error code you're trying to disable, import-untype, is not recognized by mypy. The correct error code for disabling the import-related errors would be import-untyped
So, you could simply change out your mypy.ini configuration in for:
[mypy]
disable_error_code = import-untyped,override

